# Cron job full path: Still getting broken pipe errors

Tags: php, bash, unix, ssh, cron

I know that what I'm doing wrong is not including the right, full file path information but after hours of tweeking I'm still getting a `sh: 2012-06-08-01-25.sql.gz: Permission denied mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write` error. Here's my script:

```
$dbhost = "DATABASE HOST";
$dbuser = "DATABSE USER";
$dbpass = 'PASSWORD';
$dbname = "DATABASE NAME";

$backupfile = '/home/12345/data/backup/'.date("Y-m-dTH:i") . '.sql.gz';
system("mysqldump -h $dbhost -u $dbuser --password='$dbpass' $dbname | gzip > $backupfile");

$backupfile = $backupfile;

# To S3
require('/home/12345/data/backup/S3.php');  

if (!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey', 'ACCESS KEY');  
if (!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey', 'SECRET KEY');  

$s3 = new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

if (!$s3->putObjectFile($backupfile, "BUCKET", 'db-backup/'.$backupfile, S3::ACL_PRIVATE)) {  
    die("104");
}
system("rm $backupfile");
```

The script is zipping my database using gzip and mysqldump, and then uploading this ZIP to a secure, encrypted folder on an S3 bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key:

```
sh: 2012-06-08-01-25.sql.gz: Permission denied
```

Chown/chgrp to a user/group with write permissions and/or modify permissions with chmod so the executing user/group can read/write to the destination directory.

The pipe is broken because it cannot write the file, permission denied.

Comment: That would be `chown` rather than `chmod`.

Comment: Either or would work depending on your comfort level and knowledge of the OS, although most would consider chown to be more secure.

Comment: They do two different things and it's necessary to use each of them for their appropriate functions. There's no overlap. I suggest you go read their `man` pages.

Comment: Why chown a directory to a new user/group if a user trying to write to said directory is already a member of the group, but the permissions don't allow group w? Example, multiple users need to write to the same directory, you would group them up and give the group write permissions...

Comment: You said "...chmod...to the user..." -`chmod` doesn't take a user as an argument. What you would need to do is `chgrp` the directory to the group name (`chgrp groupname dirname`) and `chmod` the group write permissions (`chmod g+w dirname`). I think you and I are having a simple misunderstanding about the way we're using terminology. I would suggest that you try to be more precise.

Comment: I would agree. I have updated my response to reflect updated terminology.

Comment: I'm currently using a Media Temple Grid Server, I can't see any way to change Cron users' permissions?

Comment: In a shared environment, it is very dangerous to play around with permission settings. Luckily, most secure hosts will employ the use of jailshell or chroot, which limits the access of directories outside the users assigned path. If you run an `ls -la /home/12345/data/ | grep backup`, what permissions are currently assigned to the directory?

Comment: Do not change the user running the cron job to root; make sure that you know which directory you are backing up to, and make sure that the user running the cron job can write in that directory.  Or make a directory for the backup to be created in.  The key is the directory permissions, but using `root` is a bad sledgehammer to apply to a small nut.

Comment: The current permissions for the /backup along with /data is to 770

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have permission to write to /home/12345/data/backup. Ensure that the permissions allow the user that Apache runs as to write to the specified directory by changing the owner of the folder to the Apache user and read/execute for everyone else:

```
chown {*APACHE-USER*} /home/12345/data/backup
chmod 755 /home/12345/data/backup
```

Comment: NO! Don't set permissions to 777! I can't think of any circumstances in which this is the right thing to do!

Comment: He is using this directory effectively as a temp directory to upload to S3. A bit presumptuous on my part, but I assume it would be cleared, regularly, after successful upload. You are correct, though, that the most secure setting permission should be set depending on who/what should be writing to the directory. I've updated my answer to reflect the more proper method.

Comment: Changing the permissions of the directory didn't help either?